# StackOverflowError in Java while working with arrays and recursion

Tags: java, arrays, memory-management, stack-overflow

The lifeCycle-method in my MatrixCreatureContainer-class throws a stack overflow error after about 3-4k iterations. Why is that? I assume it has something to do with memory allocation, but I cannot figure out how to solve it. I tried reading about the java garbage collector, but nothing I did seemed to help.

```java
public class MatrixCreatureContainer {

    private final static int NUMBER_OF_CREATURES = 20;
    private static Random rand;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        rand = new Random();
        List<MatrixCreature> population = new ArrayList<MatrixCreature>();

        for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CREATURES ; i++){
            population.add(new MatrixCreature());
        }

        Collections.sort(population);

        lifeCycle(population,0, 4000);
    }

    private static void lifeCycle(List<MatrixCreature> population, int generation, int iterations){

        if (generation == iterations) return;

        List<MatrixCreature> newPopulation = new ArrayList<MatrixCreature>();

        while(population.size() != 0){
            MatrixCreature mother = population.remove(rand.nextInt(population.size()));
            MatrixCreature father = population.remove(rand.nextInt(population.size()));
            newPopulation.add(new MatrixCreature(mother,father));
            newPopulation.add(new MatrixCreature(mother,father));
            newPopulation.add(new MatrixCreature(mother,father));
        }

        Collections.sort(newPopulation);

        newPopulation = newPopulation.subList(0,NUMBER_OF_CREATURES);

        lifeCycle(newPopulation,generation + 1, iterations);

    }

}
```

The MatrixCreature-class basically only holds an integer array (int[]) of 20 integers. The constructor takes in two other matrixCreatures, and combines the arrays of two the matrixCreatures given, with a small chance of mutation. Each matrixCreature gets a score (where 0 is the best) of how close the sum of the numbers in the array is to 55. It's that score the population of each generation in the MatrixCreatureContainer is sorted by, such that the 20 "best" of each generation survives.
I can post the code to the MatrixCreature-class if it's relevant.

Thanks in advance :)

-Boye

Comment: How are you calling it? (What are the values of `generation` and `iterations` in the initial call?)

Comment: @JonSkeet I call it from the main method, I updated the code in the question :)

Comment: `while(population.size() != 0){`: shouldn't that be `while(population.size() > 1){` ? (other hint: you don't seem to be in need of recursion at all here)

Comment: So you start with the generation of 0 and recurse until your generation is 4000 (as there are no other termination conditions). Possibly an algorithm that recurses 4K times is far from being optimal... it feels like a misuse of recursion :) The JVM stack size is OS specific, being only 128K on Linux32 or on Windows64: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/jrdocs/refman/optionX.html#wp1024112

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this call:

```
lifeCycle(population,0, 4000);
```

you're basically asking for a stack with 4000 frames (at least - see later). That isn't *totally* beyond reason, but in fact there's no reason to make this recursive at all. You can easily just change the method to be iterative - and even remove the `generation` parameter:

```
private static void lifeCycle(List<MatrixCreature> population, int iterations) {
    for (int generation = 0; generation < iterations; generation++) {
        // Body of previous method here
    }
}
```

Additionally, you keep creating views using `newPopulation = newPopulation.subList(...)`. You probably don't want to do that - it means that every operation will need to go through a huge number of stack frames, as each call to a view will delegate to its underlying list... and if that's another view, it needs to keep going, etc. Icky. If those view calls actually require a couple of stack frames per "layer" you could easily end up with a stack of around 12K calls in your original code...

I would suggest creating a *copy* of the relevant portion of the list on each iteration instead - and then returning the final list.

Answer (score 0):

Each lifecycle starts with its own `population` and creates a new one for the next generation (with always 3 creatures inside; is this intended ?)

So after 4000 iterations you have those 4000 population lists hanging around as they never went out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

Java does not support tail-recursion optimization, so your last line in the `lifeCycle` method creates a new stack frame for every iteration.

With your memory size, and the number of local variables, you have determined that you can have about 4000 stack frames. Solution: rewrite your method using a for-loop. It's a small change, you don't really need recursion for your method.